# Cannot include msclr\marshal_cppstd.h - _This_conversion_is_not_supported

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++-cli, interop

I have a CLI project, that is using marshal to convert String^ to std::string.
For some reason when I include the header, I get these compile errors that I don't seem to understand.

Even when I don't make any calls to marshal_as, I still get the compile errors.

I've looked online to no help.

Maybe you can help?

Code:

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>


namespace ConnectionWrapper
{
  inline std::string ToStdString(System::String^ str)
  {
    return msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(str);
  }

  inline System::String^ ToCliString(const std::string std)
  {
    return msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(std);
  }
}
```

Compile Errors:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\msclr\marshal.h(222): error C3861: '_This_conversion_is_not_supported': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\msclr\marshal.h(224): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'msclr::interop::error_reporting_helper<_To_Type,_From_Type,false>' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\msclr\marshal.h(233): error C3861: '_This_conversion_requires_a_context': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\msclr\marshal.h(235): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'msclr::interop::error_reporting_helper<_To_Type,_From_Type,true>' being compiled
```

Comment: That is indeed hard to understand, seems your std::string does not match the std::string that the marshal_as template uses.  Use the /showIncludes compile option to ensure you are not #including a weirdo copy of the `<string>` header file.  You do need to document your VS2017 version in your question, use Help > About.

Comment: I solved the problem.. though I don't really understand how. -- I turned off the /permissive flag -- and everything built fine

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem.. though I don't really understand how. -- I turned off the /permissive flag -- and everything built fine

Answer (score 1):

Thanks very much for this suggestion, I just came across the same issue.

Turning off the `/permissive` flag solved it. By the way, I noticed that the flag is turned of for C++ CLR Empty Project for Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS), whereas Windows Console Project has it on (VS 2017/.Net 4.7).

Answer (score 0):

For building /clr with C++20, use the compile option /Zc:twoPhase-

For reference see [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/msclrmarshal_h-headers-still-require/10367370?space=21&entry=problem&sort=newest).